# как конвертировать MemberExpression в json

Tags: c#, сериализация, .net-5, blazor-server-side

у меня есть класс

```
    public record MyProperty(MemberExpression PropertyExpression)
    {
        internal static MyProperty FromExpression<T>(Expression<Func<MyObj, T>> expression) =>
            new (ValidatePropertyExpression(expression));

        internal static MyProperty FromExpression(MemberExpression expression) =>
            new (ValidatePropertyExpression(expression));

        private static MemberExpression ValidatePropertyExpression(MemberExpression member)
        {
            return member;
        }
    }
```

я создаю екземпляры вот так

```
    var p = SearchableProperty.FromExpression(o => o.Title);
    var p = SearchableProperty.FromExpression(o => o.Object.Title);
    var p = SearchableProperty.FromExpression(o => o.IsCorrect);
```

тоесть может храниться любой тип(Object, string, bool и тд)

**Мне необходимо сохранить объект в json(в любом виде) и потом обратно из json сделать объект**

Comment: Приведите конкретный пример, как это должно работать. Что бы вы хотели увидеть в выходной строке с json?

Comment: все что угодно, главное что бы потом можно было из этого сделать обратно

Comment: Например что именно?

Comment: ну что бы я обратно смог получить MyProperty из того json`а, если можно так

Comment: можно даже оставить q.Object или q.Object.Text и тд. главное что бы можно было вернуть обратно

Comment: Лично мне все еще непонятно, что вам нужно. Но может быть кто-нибудь другой поможет.

Comment: все что мне нужно это сохранить объект в json в котором одно из полей является типом MemberExpression, а потом вернуть обрятно из строки json в обьект

Comment: [Оно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29684179/12888024)?

Comment: Отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки [edit] под вопросом. Не нужно дублировать вопрос.